# Using a solid state relay in a car

Tags: electrical, ignition, security, remote-start

I have this project where I'd like to put a SSR in the ignition, to control whether or not it can be started. I'm not sure what power requirements are though. My vehicle is an 01 Oldsmobile Alero v6.

Now I have little experience here. I've been told a SSR can act as a switch.

Comment: This question needs more explanation. Are you looking to install a way to disable your starter? Or are you looking to control the starter of the engine with a solid state relay?

Comment: Ditto on @EricUrban's comment, it would help a lot to know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Let me get this straight... You want to install a switch to disable the ignition on your 15 year old Oldsmobile because you think vehicle is a target to be stolen and your switch would prevent this?

Comment: No, @cory, I'm bored. I wanted a project to work on, and building a killswitch so sorts sounds pretty cool.

Comment: "in the ignition, to control whether or not it can be started". I figured that was more than clear enough, but just call it a killswitch (or just a switch). I want to electronically be able to disable the ignition.

Answer (score 1):

A solid-state relay is an electronic switch, you'd need to find one designed to controlled by, nominally, 12 V DC and that would also switch DC loads. You'll need to know the current requirements of the load that you're switching to decide on the output capacity of the SSR that you need.

It's also worth noting that solid-state switches impose a voltage drop on the switched load, that might cause you problems (or it might be fine, either way you need to think about it).

Mechanical relays have much smaller output voltage drops (approaching zero), so unless there is a compelling reason to use a SSR, I'd be inclined to go with a mechanical relay.

Comment: I'm not set on SSR, I was suggested it by someone else. I was hoping to use a raspberry pi 3 for this, and use it to control a relay. How would I determine the load? By the battery?

Answer (score 0):

The most common types of SSR are made for controlling AC like you get from the power mains. These typically will not work with DC circuits as you have in a vehicle. There are probably better ways of disabling the ignition circuit and you probably need to do some more detailed analysis of the circuit.  Certainly you need to acquire the wiring diagram for the vehicle. And study of that will probably reveal one or more points where you could accomplish your goal.